# check whether a List<string> contains an element in another List<string> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How do I check whether a List contains an element that exists in another List using LINQ in C#? I don't want to use a for/while loop.

So, if List1 has A, B, C and List2 has B, 1, 2, then I would return true.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<string> a = ...
List<string> b = ...
var inComon = a.Intersect(b).Any();
```

Answer (score 14):

Use [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx):

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string> { "1", "3" };
var result = l2.Any(s => l1.Contains(s));
```

I'd say the `Intersect` method (see answer by *dasblinkenlight*) + `Any` must work better than `Contains` + `Any`. It is definetely better to use `Any` than `Count`.

Comment: You can even make it neater with `l1.Any(l2.Contains)`

Comment: Thanks for an excellent suggestion, `Any` is definitely better than `Count() != 0`!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight my +1 to you for `Intersect`...actually I forgot about it at first...and I do like it more

Comment: I have a list with sentences. I have an array with particular words. I want indexes of the list if the sentence have atleast one words from the array @horgh