# Compare a List<string> to a SQL column value to decide if a list item appears in the column

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [check whether a List<string> contains an element in another List<string> using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715529/check-whether-a-liststring-contains-an-element-in-another-liststring-using-l)

A SQL database column stores a bunch of strings like so: /String1/String2/String3/... with the first and last characters being '/'. I need to compare this column to a `List<string>` to decide whether a parameter string in the list is contained in the column value.

Column value: "/One/Two/Three/Four/"

Parameter: `List<string> parameters = new List<string>{"Two", "Three"};`

Compare the parameter list to the column value. Since at least one item appears in the column value, return true / select the row.

I'm using LINQ-to-SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), [Enumerable.Intersect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) and [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx):

```
//I guess you can get the string representation of the column value
string value = "/One/Two/Three/Four/"; 
List<string> parameters = new List<string> { "Two", "Three" };

bool result = value.Split('/')
                   .Intersect(parameters)
                   .Any();
```