# check whether a List<string> contains an element in another List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a list with sentences. I have another List with particular words. I want the sentences from the list, if the sentence have at least one words from the list below. That sentence should be selected and stored in a variable.

```
 List<string> features = new List<string>(new string[] { "battery", "screen", "audio" });
```

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: yes I have done it using nested loops.. I am looking for a better way

Comment: Please include your attempt even if failed so we know you tried something and not expecting us to write code for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check whether a List<string> contains an element in another List<string> using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715529/check-whether-a-liststring-contains-an-element-in-another-liststring-using-l)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq `Any` with `Contains` should to this

```
List<string> features = new List<string>(){ "battery", "screen", "audio" };
List<string> sentences = new List<string>() { "this is a new screen", "i need a new battery", "there is no foo in my bar" };
List<string> result = sentences.Where(x => features.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

Comment: that condition will return true for "ineedanewbattery"

Comment: the OP is not clear enough defined if this is supposed to be valid or not

Answer (score -1):

you can use linq.

```
List<string> features = new List<string>(new string[] { "battery", "screen", "audio" });
// or simpler
//List<string> features = new List<string>{ "battery", "screen", "audio" };

List<string> listOfLines = GetAllLinesHereInList();
var filteredLines = listOfLines.Where(ln=>features.Any(f=>ln.IndexOf(f) > -1));
```